# Preserving part of a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

When drawing on a HTML5 canvas element, is it possible to leave part of it untouched? Can you take part of the image, and then redraw that part if its not directly possible?

The only solution I have thought of is to draw to a seprate, smaller canvas and then copy that over to the main canvas. Is this a feasible approach?

I wish to draw a game scene while preserving the ui. Unfortunately, the draw order is not known in advance.

Comment: Do you want to draw a cropped part of an image on the canvas?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to restrict the output of drawImage to a specific region. I could manually filter each image, and then crop it, based on coordinates, but was hoping for an inbuilt high performance solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [`.clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing#Clipping_paths): http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/122/.

```
ctx.rect(100, 50, 200, 100);          // make a region
ctx.clip();                           // constrain to that region
ctx.drawImage($("img").get(0), 0, 0); // draw image
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I am looking for, however, it tanked my performance. It makes chrome completely unresponsive. Is this a very slow action to perform? Is once a frame not feasible?

Comment: @Venatu: I'm using it in a renderer of mine, calling it about 80 times each frame and it's not the bottleneck. In fact it seems to be faster than drawing the complete image (without clipping). On a side note, are you using the beta/dev channel? GPU is enabled for canvas there, which makes for a horrible performance, at least that's what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Worth noting: if you need to clip out a complex region, you can do so using oriented curves. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/123/)

Comment: @pimvdb Yes I am using the beta channel. Ill switch over to the stable and post the results. Using requestAnimationFrame makes it slighter more responsive, though not by much. Seems like a bug from what you say

Comment: @Venatu: Just to make sure, are you 1) saving and restoring the canvas 2) creating a new path each time? Otherwise you'll snow the canvas under with paths, which of course does have a drawback in performance.

Comment: @Venatu: I set up a simple FPS counter; it's running at 62 fps for me, which is my screen rate: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/125/. Are you experiencing the same?

Comment: @pimvdb I was saving and restoring. It worked fine in safari, and works in chrome now I've changed the order around a bit. I think I wasn't batching my draws properly. Thanks for the answers, very appreciated!

Just saw the second comment, Ive capped mine at 30, but I expect Id get about the same now.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the UI on another canvas. You can layer canvas elements if need be.

HTML

```
<div id="gameframe">
    <canvas id="game-ui"></canvas>
    <canvas id="game"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#gameFrame { position: relative; width: 800px; height: 800px;}
#game-ui { position: absolute; z-index: 10; bottom: 0; left; 0; height: 50px; width: 100%;}
#game { position: absolute; z-index: 5; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

Yields

```
-------------------------------------------------------
-                                                     -
-                                                     -
-                                                     -
-                <canvas id="game">                   -
-                                                     -
-                                                     -
-                                                     -
-                                                     -
-------------------------------------------------------
-               <canvas id="game-ui">                 -
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating Canvas games i've always layered the GUI on top of the game canvas.

```
#ui{position: fixed; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; z-index: 1000; width: 500; height: 500}
#game{position: fixed; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; z-index: 999}

<div id="ui"><!--UI elements--></div>
<canvas id="game" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Obviously you can layer another canvas on top, or build the UI using html elements.